# Firebase Cloud Messaging - PHP REST API not working on iOS

Tags: php, android, ios, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using below PHP code to send push notification to Android and iOS devices using Firebase REST API. Push notifications are coming fine in Android device. But it is not coming in iOS device.

Meanwhile, when I send the notification from the Firebase console, both devices are receiving it. Did I miss anything in my API implementation?

```
$data = array("to" => "/topics/news",
              'priority' => '10',
              'notification' => array('body' => $msg));

$headers = array
(
    'Authorization: key='.$apiKey,
    'Content-Type: application/json'
);

try {
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);                                                                  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    $ouput = curl_exec($ch);

    if ($ouput === false) {
        throw new Exception(curl_error($ch), curl_errno($ch));
    }

    $response = curl_getinfo($ch);
} catch(Exception $e) {}
```

Comment: Can you print out how your payload is interpreted? If I'm reading it right, it would be showing a payload where your `notification` is inside the `data`? Also, try setting the `priority` to `high` instead of `10`.

Comment: Yes. After setting priority to high it is working fine. If you post it as an answer, i'll accept it.

Comment: I'll go ahead and do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set your `priority` to `high` instead of `10`.

When using GCM/FCM, the only valid values for `priority` are `normal` and `high` which is equal to `5` and `10` for iOS APNs, as was mentioned [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#downstream-http-messages-json):

> Sets the priority of the message. Valid values are "normal" and "high." On iOS, these correspond to APNs priorities 5 and 10.